Запись текста N-ое количество раз в переменную string
Есть некоторая переменная string, цикл for и переменная int.
Хотелось бы записать в string результат многократной записи какого то символа, чтобы потом можно было возвратить этот результат в функцию, для многократного использования
private static string stro4ka(string[] args)
{
    int time = 100;
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < time; i++)
    {
        //???????????????????????
    }
    return; //?????????????????????
}

Результат должен быть примерно таким:
..........................................


Простым способом будет обычное line += "символ";, но это не очень эффективно с точки зрения памяти и не очень правильно с точки зрения здравого смысла. В случае построения строки через циклы лучше всего использовать StringBuilder (например, так), хотя в случае создания простой строки из одинаковых символов определенной длины достаточно простой конструкции new string(char c, int count), где c - нужный символ, а count - сколько раз его нужно повторить в строке (в данном примере - string result = new string('.', 100); сделает строку из 100 точек).

У строки есть конструктор который принимает символ и количество его повторений.

По вашему коду:
private static string stro4ka(string[] args)
{
    int time = 100;
    string line = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < time; i++)
    {
        line += "."
    }
    return line;
}

Либо такой вариант:
private static string stro4ka(string[] args)
{
    int time = 100;
    return new string(".", time);
}

Вообще, если вам нужен вывод, тогда это всё нужно ещё поместить в метод для вывода на экран .WriteLine. Насколько я понимаю по string[] args, это где-то примерно возле Main'а, тогда буде примерно вот так:
private static string stro4ka(string[] args)
{
    // Любая из предыдущих реализаций
    Console.WriteLine(line)
}


Да вот именно, что возможно и не нужно эту строчку хранить вообще, если это нужно только для вывода в консоль, например. Можно просто вывести символ нужное количество раз в консоль, да и всё. Но для чего точно эта строка нужна из вопроса неясно.

@CrazyElf, да, возможно, но это уже от задачи автора зависит

Спасибо, друзья я понял свою ошибку и всё исправил, только вот оказывается можно указать тип метода не string, а void т.к. он не обязан ничего выполнять!
